# How to call php controller action from javascript to get json data?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call a controller action from javascript to get data in json format. I guess it should be pretty clear using `$.getJSON` function. But it doesn't work in my code. Is there anyone who can explain me what is wrong?

IndexController action

```
    public function jsonAction() 
    {
        $this->_disableView();

        $data[0]["name"] = "test";
        $data[0]["lat"] = 50.080746;
        $data[0]["long"] = 14.426373;

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

When I test it on url domain/index/json I see json as expected.
Now the relevant script in document ready function:

```
    $.getJSON("index/json",function(data){
       alert("hello");
    });
```

But no alert is shown.
In the console I can see

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).asmSelect is not a function
```

Comment: did you load the asmSelect plugin ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342484/jquery-asmselect-changes-not-firing-on-sort

Comment: Why do I need asmSelect?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).>>>>asmSelect <<<< is not a function

Comment: I see that, but don't think this is the problem why the getJSON function doesn't get the data. If I move the code from action to get_data.php file in root and call "/get_data.php" in getJSON, it works good.

Comment: I know your problem was solved, but if you ever had such a problem, try chain your `getJSON` method with `fail` method, and log the error, see [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for more information about how to use `fail` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT! I was missing slash at the behinning `$.getJSON("/index/json",function(data){});`